# Save a int value when restarting an activity

Tags: java, android, persistent-storage

I am new and I know I will get beat down for this Question but if I get the answer it will be worth it. I have a game that when the user wins the first round I want the save the score and restart the activity instead of going through all of the code and resetting every value. Now How do I keep the score from resetting when the Activity restarts. I dont  have example as of yet.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
// SET UP SPINS
private TextView spins;
private Button spin;

// SET UP CONTROLS
private TextView score;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private static final int SHOW_BONUSACTIVITY = 1;
    int nextspin = 0;
int alert;
int total = 0;
int totalspins = 14;
public int gamescore = 0;
public int currentgamescore = 0;

   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.play_layout);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Here is where I  check if a new game for the first time or if there was a highscore saved to be used here

```
if (GameState.INSTANCE.getScore() != 0){
        gamescore = GameState.INSTANCE.getScore();}
```

IF USER WINS THEN THEY ARE SENT TO A BONUS GAME THEN BACK TO SEE IF THEY HAVE FINISHED THE GAME AND NEEDS TO START A NEW

```
   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case (SHOW_BONUSACTIVITY): {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            int bonus = data.getIntExtra("money", 0);
            gamescore=(gamescore + bonus);
            score.setText(String.valueOf("SCORE: " + gamescore));
            if (bigwin == true){
```

HERE IS WHERE I SAVE THE GAMESCORE TO BRING IT INTO THE NEW ACTIVITY IF THEY WON THE FIRST LEVEL.

```
                GameState.INSTANCE.addScore(gamescore);
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                MainActivity.this,
                com.bigdaddyapp.android.blingo.MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);  


            }
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

the next code is the enum activity

```
public enum GameState {
INSTANCE;

  private int score;
  private GameState(){
    score = 0;
  }

  public int getScore(){
    return score;
  }
  public void addScore(int score){
    this.score += score;
  }

}
```

Comment: Removed Activity tag, added persistent-storage tag.

Comment: WOW! thanks for the input I will try them all and get back to check the best answer that works for my use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to storing the values persistent (using Shared Preferences or a SQLite Database), you can also store the values in memory but in a more global context. This way, you'll keep the state over your re-creation of the Activity, but the application will forget them when it's closed.

This might not be what you need for your particular case, but sometimes it's the better option.

---

**Using a Singleton**, you can store the state of your application more globally and retrieve it at any point in your code. An example might be:

```
public enum GameState{
  INSTANCE;

  private int score;
  private GameState(){
    score = 0;
  }

  public int getScore(){
    return score;
  }
  public void addScore(int score){
    this.score += score;
  }

}
```

It can be used by simply writing:

```
GameState.INSTANCE.addScore(20);
GameState.INSTANCE.getScore();
```

There are multiple ways to implement a singleton. In my example, I used the approach Joshua Bloch documented in his Book "Effective Java - Second Edition". [See wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_Enum_way) for more information.

---

**Extending `android.app.Application`** is another option, thought not as recommended as using the singleton. From [the JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html):

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state.
>   You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your
>   AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that class
>   to be instantiated for you when the process for your
>   application/package is created.

A tutorial on how to do this might be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3779802/717341) (and the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables/708317#708317)).

Comment: Lukas can you look at this again and tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: When I call the mainActivity to restart the score starts over at 0 and I lose the gamescore that I wanted to bring to the restart of the new game.

Comment: I am truly sorry it was my mistake. I had code just below that I didn't show that set the value of gamescore to = 0when I removed that it worked like you stated. Thanks the correct code has been added to the example above.

Comment: @sai no, as mentioned in the answer. This will survive as long as the application is running (in back- or foreground), but will be forgotten when the app is closed (all activities finished).

Comment: @sai see **Raghav Sood**'s answer, below mine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) as a simple persistent storage mechanism to save things like the score, lives etc. When the level gets over, save the score via [putInt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and when you want to get the score use [getInt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Comment: Nice , I will try that now and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I guess my question wasn't that bad no one ripped me a new one but can I get a 1 up?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to end the game, do this:

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putInt("gamevariable", gamevariable);

  editor.commit();
```

Then in your onCreate method, get back your variable and use it as you wish:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
myvariable = settings.getInt("gamevariable", false);
```

As an alternative, I would use standard serialization, which is a more complicated but yet easy option.

First write your integer to a .ser file that you can read later and save it into your project directory:

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("myinteger.ser");
ObjectOutput oo = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
oo.writeObject(myinteger);
oo.close();
```

Then read back your integer into a variable next time you load your activity:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("myinteger.ser");
ObjectInput oi = new ObjectInputStream(is);
int myinteger = (int) oi.readObject();
oi.close();
```